# data extraction from webpage using Xpath in php

Tags: php, html, regex, xpath

I need to extract data from [here](https://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/www.currys.co.uk). 
The webpage contains review comments, review headline, number of reviews which are found useful and rating ( in stars ) and i need to extract those.

1. The problem now i face i am able to retrieve only the review comment and that too which is present first in the page( it doesnt move to next review comment )....
2. I am not able to retrieve the review headline as it comes with differnt object id in the html .

ex: ( can i use regex for object id in this case? )

```
<a href="/review/www.currys.co.uk/5370859f00006400028963d9">Customer services what a load of cp</a>
```

Also i don't know how to get the number of reviews found useful and rating 1 to 5 as they are indicated in icons.

My code:

```
$url = "https://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/www.currys.co.uk";
$html = file_get_contents( $url);
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument; $doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);
$node = $xpath->query( '//div[@itemprop="reviewBody"][@class="review-body"]')->item( 0);
echo $node  >textContent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's showing only the first one now is because you have selected only for `->item( 0)`, you need to loop through them. Also, to print the elements inside the tag, you use `nodeValue` (you have tried `textContent` which doesn't exist).

The following code prints 10 reviews in table with the rating (stars), headlines and content:

```
$url = "https://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/www.currys.co.uk";
$html = file_get_contents( $url);
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument; $doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);
//get all ratings where <meta itemprop="ratingValue">
$ratings = $xpath->query('//meta[@itemprop="ratingValue"]');
//get all headings where <h3 class="review-title en h4">
$headings = $xpath->query( '//h3[@class="review-title en h4"]');
//get all content
$node = $xpath->query( '//div[@itemprop="reviewBody"][@class="review-body"]');

$table = "<table border=1>";
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
$table .= '<tr>
           <td>Star: '.str_repeat("*",$ratings->item($i)->getAttribute('content')).'</tr>
           <td>'.$headings->item($i)->nodeValue.'</tr>
           <td>'.$node->item($i)->nodeValue.'</tr>
           </tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Comment: @I Can Has Kittenz , thanks a lot for your help. I am doing analysis with those reviews. i have only 2 more doubts left. 1. Is it possible that we can count the rating eg : 1 star = 1 which means bad, 5 star = 5 which means very good. 2. there are 794 reviews posted for that company .but i could use the maximum value 20 in the for loop mentioned . can we get it by some processing ?

Comment: @I Can Has Kittenz , a small update . I have got the rating part.only thing which i am struggling is to get the review count ( totally 794 review comments have been posted , but i could loop through only till the value of 20 in the for loop) to provide in the for loop.is it possible to make it loop through all the review comments ?

Comment: @vds It seems like they use AJAX to load more pages, however it seems you can access each page by changing the URL: https://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/www.currys.co.uk?page=2 for the second page, totally there are 40 pages, you could put the above code in a for loop for 40 times and keep incrementing the `page` in the URL. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: @I Can Has Kittenz , thank you . i went upon as you told , but program  stopped after sometime with the following error " Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\auth\truspilot.php on line 5 " . Line 5 is "$html = file_get_contents( $url); " . it can execute only for certain period of time ?

Comment: @vds You're right, it seems at the most to handle only 8-10. Loading all the lists at once is not possible, if you need them in one page, use AJAX just like the way the website has done. When you click on "load more" using AJAX send a request to PHP to load the contents of the next page.